# Get a second implicit derivative with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

we have the follow cell in jupyter kernel python3:

```
from sympy.interactive.printing import init_printing
from sympy.core.symbol import symbols
from sympy.geometry.util import idiff
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
```

then just run:

```
eq = x ** 2 - x * y + y ** 2 - 3
eqd1 = idiff(eq, y, x)
eqd1
```

we get the correct answer: 2x-y / x-2y

but if run the code:

```
eqd2 = idiff(eqd1, y, x)
eqd2
```

we get: x/y but the answer realy is: 18/(x-2y)² or 6(x²-xy+y²)/(x-2y)³

x/y and 18/(x-2y)² don't looks like a equal expression or factorial one of another

Comment: I couldn't find `sympy,geometry.util.idiff` in the docs. How is it different from `diff`? I assume the difference is somehow related to geometry, but how? It seems like something like `diff(eq, y) / diff(eq, x)` but maybe with the explicit assumption that it's differentiating about `eq==0`?

Comment: abarnert, maybe idiff is not in the docs but please run in a cell of jupyter python3 and you'll see realy works this statement in the cell, and works for the first derivative. (revise you use comma to import instead point).

Comment: OK, it "works" to do what exactly? Without knowing what it's expected to do differently from `diff` or `Derivative`, it's hard to know why it's doing something different than some expectation.

Comment: You can find the implementation/documenation of idiff at [here](http://docs.sympy.org/1.0/_modules/sympy/geometry/util.html).

Comment: "to do exactly" get the first derivative abartnert

Comment: Aha: "Return dy/dx assuming that eq == 0". I thought it was something like that. Which means it's not just "get the first derivative" of eq after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running

```
eqd2 = idiff(eq, y, x, n=2)
simplify(expand(eqd2))
```

Produces

> 6(x<sup>2</sup>-xy+y<sup>2</sup>)/(x<sup>3</sup>-6x<sup>2</sup>y-12xy<sup>2</sup>-8y<sup>3</sup>)

which is the correct result (after a bit more simplification).

Comment: Right. The point being, computing y'' based on F(x, y) = 0 cannot be split as computing y', letting the result be G(x, y), and then computing the derivative based on G(x, y) = 0. The equation G(x, y) = 0 describes something totally different.